# creating a launch page in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, launch

I am planning to create an app in rails but first I want to make a launch page.  Having never made a launch page I am curious as to how others are doing it?

Do you creae a small rails application with controller and model that just collects email addresses? and then deploy the rails app? I'd prefer this way but it seems like an overkill to deploy a rails app just for a launch page...?

Also, how do you modify the routes file so that if users type anything after the url then only page that shows up is the laungh page.

Meaning, if my launch page is at `http://mycoollaunchpage.com` then if users mess around and type `http://mycoollaunchpage.com/lkjlkjljk` then it should redirect back to `http://mycoollaunchpage.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea sounds good. Just a page with an email signup form would work well.

To redirect back to your home page, make a route glob in your `routes.rb` file, and have an action in your controller that just redirects back to your root.

```
# in routes.rb
match "*whatever", :controller => 'pages', :action => 'redirect_to_root'

# in your pages_controller.rb file
def redirect_to_root
  redirect_to "/"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome rails plugin available for this very requirement of yours ;)

https://github.com/vinsol/Launching-Soon/

Comment: that gem has way too much information for a launching page. I think my needs will suffice if I just take an email address and dump it on a database and later migrate the emails out. Good find though!